# Pandas division with 2 dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I want to divide 2 dfs by matching their names.  For example,

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['xy-yz','xa-ab','yz-ijk','zb-ijk'],1:[1,2,3,4],2:[1,2,1,2],3:[2,2,2,2]} )`

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name2':['x','y','z','a'],1:[0,1,2,3],2:[1,2,3,4],3:[5,5,5,6]})`

df1:

```
Name1    1   2   3
xy-yz    1   1   2
xa-ab    2   2   2
yz-ijk   3   1   2
zb-ijk   4   2   2
```

df2:

```
Name2   1   2   3
x       0   1   5
y       1   2   5
z       2   3   5
a       3   4   6
```

The result would be df3:

```
Name1    1   2   3
xy-yz    1   1   2
x        0   1   5
xy-yz        1   .4   <---(xy-yz)/x   
xa-ab    2   2   2
x        0   1   5
xa-ab        2   .4    <---(xa-ab)/x
yz-ijk   3   1   2
y        1   2   5
yz-ijk   3   .5  .4    <---(yz-ijk)/y
zb-ijk   4   2   2
z        2   3   5
zb-ijk   2   .67 .4    <---(zb-ijk)/z
```

I would use concat but I'm not not sure how to do the division by mapping the Name2 to the first letter in Name1 here.

Thank you!

Comment: Performing division is easy enough. The challenge is this weird output representation you have ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it doesn't have to be in that format.  I would just use concat(df1,df2,division) there.  I arranged like that so it's easier to everyone to understand the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup -

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Name')
df2 = df2.set_index('Name2')
```

```
df1

        1  2  3
Name           
xy-yz   1  1  2
xa-ab   2  2  2
yz-ijk  3  1  2
zb-ijk  4  2  2

df2

       1  2  3
Name2         
x      0  1  5
y      1  2  5
z      2  3  5
a      3  4  6
```

Retrieve relevant rows from `df2` based on the first letter of `df1`.

```
i = df2.loc[df1.index.str[0]]
i

       1  2  3
Name2         
x      0  1  5
x      0  1  5
y      1  2  5
z      2  3  5
```

Perform divison and reset the index.

```
j = (df1.set_index(i.index) / i).set_index(df1.index)
j
               1         2    3
Name                           
xy-yz        inf  1.000000  0.4
xa-ab        inf  2.000000  0.4
yz-ijk  3.000000  0.500000  0.4
zb-ijk  2.000000  0.666667  0.4
```

Concatenate the result.

```
pd.concat([df1, i, j])

               1         2    3
xy-yz   1.000000  1.000000  2.0
xa-ab   2.000000  2.000000  2.0
yz-ijk  3.000000  1.000000  2.0
zb-ijk  4.000000  2.000000  2.0
x       0.000000  1.000000  5.0
x       0.000000  1.000000  5.0
y       1.000000  2.000000  5.0
z       2.000000  3.000000  5.0
xy-yz        inf  1.000000  0.4
xa-ab        inf  2.000000  0.4
yz-ijk  3.000000  0.500000  0.4
zb-ijk  2.000000  0.666667  0.4
```

---

Here, once again, use `np.isfinite` on `j` if you want to mask non-real numeric values -

```
j  = j[np.isfinite(j)].fillna('')
j

        1         2    3
Name                    
xy-yz      1.000000  0.4
xa-ab      2.000000  0.4
yz-ijk  3  0.500000  0.4
zb-ijk  2  0.666667  0.4
```

Use *this* `j` as the argument to concatenation afterwards.

Comment: just some minor adjustment, instead of df1.index.str[0] , can we search until " -"?  For example, 
For xyz - abc, if we use df1.index.str[0] we'll get x, how would we get the full zyz?

Comment: @TylerNG `df1.index.str.split('-').str[0]`?

Comment: @TylerNG Okay, I guess one of the statements should be changed to `df2.loc[df1.index.str.split('-').str[0].str.strip()]`

Comment: @TylerNG Also, just keep in mind that changing the data/question invalidates the answers, so try not to do it too often :-)

Comment: Opps I did not know that.  I tried i = df2.loc[df1.index.str.split('-').str[0]] but I'm keep getting "None of [Index(['1', '2', '2'...      dtype='object', name='Label')] are in the [index]".  Let me adjust it w my actual data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161763/discussion-between-tylerng-and-cs).

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why you need it , but this give back what you need

```
df2=df2.set_index('Name2')
dfNew=df2.reindex(df1.Name1.str.split('-',expand=True)[0])
df1=df1.set_index('Name1')
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),dfNew.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Name1'}),pd.DataFrame(df1.values/dfNew.values,columns=df1.columns).assign(Name1=df1.index)]).sort_index()


Out[897]: 
          1         2    3  Name1
0  1.000000  1.000000  2.0   x-yz
0  0.000000  1.000000  5.0      x
0       inf  1.000000  0.4   x-yz
1  2.000000  2.000000  2.0   x-ab
1  0.000000  1.000000  5.0      x
1       inf  2.000000  0.4   x-ab
2  3.000000  1.000000  2.0  y-ijk
2  1.000000  2.000000  5.0      y
2  3.000000  0.500000  0.4  y-ijk
3  4.000000  2.000000  2.0  z-ijk
3  2.000000  3.000000  5.0      z
3  2.000000  0.666667  0.4  z-ijk
```

Comment: not sure why this give me the error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,10) (4,9)

Comment: @TylerNG sorry updated, Forget adding df1=df1.set_index('Name1')